# Javascript- using for loop to build 'associative' array

Tags: javascript, arrays, associative-array

I'm trying to build an array userRow{} using

```
$('#divResults tr').find('td:nth-child(2)').text();
```

which would return 12 first names, grabbing from a html table column Ex. John, Dave, ect..

```
$('#divResults tr').find('td:nth-child(3)').text();
```

returns middle names, ect.

what I've tried:

```
            for ( var i=0; i < 12; i++) {

            userRow[i]['jurorFN'] = $('#divResults tr').find('td:nth-child(2)').text();
            userRow[i]['jurorMN'] = $('#divResults tr').find('td:nth-child(3)').text();
            userRow[i]['jurorLN'] = $('#divResults tr').find('td:nth-child(4)').text();
        }
```

which won't console.log anything

I want it to loop all of the items on the table and have it so if I alert userRow[1] it would output Dave, M, Johnson (first middle last) ect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate over each `$('#divResults tr')`:

```
var userRow = [];
$('#divResults tr').each(function(i) {
    var tds = $(this).find('td');
    userRow[i] = {}
    userRow[i].jurorFN = tds.eq(2).text();
    userRow[i].jurorMN = tds.eq(3).text();
    userRow[i].jurorLN = tds.eq(4).text();
});
```

Otherwise, all you're doing is duplicating the first row into the array 12 times

---

Or with `map`:

```
var userRow = $('#divResults tr').map(function() {
    var tds = $(this).find('td');
    return {
        jurorFN: tds.eq(2).text(),
        jurorMN: tds.eq(3).text(),
        jurorLN: tds.eq(4).text()
    };
}).get();
```

---

Other cosmetic changes I made:

- Replace `.find('e:nth-child(n)')` with `.find('e').eq(n)`, since that allows `find('e')` to be calculated once and reused
- Replace `obj['validIdentifier']` with `obj.validIdentifier`

Comment: OP wants the output as 'Dave, M, Johnson' so having them as separate keys in an array element is no good.

Comment: Thank you, that was what I was trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

In js there is not something like associative array, only objects accessed in array style. I think that you should define object before you put some date into: `userRow[i] = {}`

The rest of code is unclear for me...

Answer (score 0):

Just going purely on the code you've provided, give this a go:

```
var userRow = [];
for ( var i=0; i < 12; i++) {
  var jurorFN = $('#divResults tr').find('td:nth-child(2)').text();
  var jurorMN = $('#divResults tr').find('td:nth-child(3)').text();
  var jurorLN = $('#divResults tr').find('td:nth-child(4)').text();
  var fullName = jurorFN + ' ' + jurorMN + ' ' + jurorLN;
  userRow.push(fullName);
}
console.log(userRow[0]); // up to userRow[11]
```

Comment: Where'd `:has(:checkbox:not(:checked))` come from?

Comment: Looks like it was edited out of the original question after I posted my code. Edited.

Comment: Sorry, it was accidentally left in there.